# Running out of memory when trying to add images to zip file in .net application

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I am running a web server with a mongo database. The database stores records, which include pictures stored as base64 encoded strings.

I am writing an api call that fetches several of these images from the records, builds them in .jpg images, and adds them to a zip file stored on the server.

The problem I'm running into is that the call returns with an OutOfMemory exception after only a few records, even when the total size of the images is less than 10mb, with each image being around 500kb. Here is the code I am using:

```
  using (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile())
            {

                var i = 0;
                foreach (ResidentialData resident in foundResidents)
                {
                    MemoryStream tempstream = new MemoryStream();

                    Image userImage1 = LoadImage(resident.AccountImage);

                    Bitmap tmp = new Bitmap(userImage1);
                    tmp.Save(tempstream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    tempstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    byte[] imageData = new byte[tempstream.Length];
                    tempstream.Read(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
                    zipFile.AddEntry(i + " | " + resident.Initials + " " + resident.Surname + ".jpg", imageData);


                    i++;
                    tempstream.Dispose();
                }
                zipFile.Save(@"C:\temp\test.zip");
            }
```

Any ideas as to what might be eating up all the memory? I don't see how this is possible as the machine it is running on has 32gb of RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dispose your bitmaps.

Change this:

```
tempstream.Dispose();
```

...to:

```
tempstream.Dispose();
tmp.Dispose();
```

You might want to look into using `using()` blocks as they allow you to define; allocate and automatically release the resource.

e.g.

```
using (var x = new SomethingThatNeedsDisposing())
{
    // do something with x
} // <----- at this point .NET will call x.Dispose() for you
```

Comment: This solved it, such a silly thing to overlook, thank you very much.